# How to deal with code that runs before foreach block in Apache Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to deal with some code that runs differently on Spark stand-alone mode and Spark running on a cluster. Basically, for each item in an **RDD**, I'm trying to add it to a list, and once this is done, I want to send this list to Solr.

This works perfectly fine when I run the following code in stand-alone mode of Spark, but does not work when the same code is run on a cluster. When I run the same code on a cluster, it is like "send to Solr" part of the code is executed before the list to be sent to Solr is filled with items. I try to force the execution by `solrInputDocumentJavaRDD.collect();` after `foreach`, but it seems like it does not have any effect.

```
// For each RDD
solrInputDocumentJavaDStream.foreachRDD(
        new Function<JavaRDD<SolrInputDocument>, Void>() {
          @Override
          public Void call(JavaRDD<SolrInputDocument> solrInputDocumentJavaRDD) throws Exception {

            // For each item in a single RDD
            solrInputDocumentJavaRDD.foreach(
                    new VoidFunction<SolrInputDocument>() {
                      @Override
                      public void call(SolrInputDocument solrInputDocument) {

                        // Add the solrInputDocument to the list of SolrInputDocuments
                        SolrIndexerDriver.solrInputDocumentList.add(solrInputDocument);
                      }
                    });

            // Try to force execution
            solrInputDocumentJavaRDD.collect();


            // After having finished adding every SolrInputDocument to the list
            // add it to the solrServer, and commit, waiting for the commit to be flushed
            try {
              if (SolrIndexerDriver.solrInputDocumentList != null
                      && SolrIndexerDriver.solrInputDocumentList.size() > 0) {
                SolrIndexerDriver.solrServer.add(SolrIndexerDriver.solrInputDocumentList);
                SolrIndexerDriver.solrServer.commit(true, true);
                SolrIndexerDriver.solrInputDocumentList.clear();
              }
            } catch (SolrServerException | IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
          }
        }
);
```

What should I do, so that sending-to-Solr part executes after the list of SolrDocuments are added to `solrInputDocumentList` (and works also in cluster mode)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned on the Spark Mailing list:
I'm not familiar with the Solr API but provided that 'SolrIndexerDriver' is a singleton, I guess that what's going on when running on a cluster is that the call to:

```
SolrIndexerDriver.solrInputDocumentList.add(elem)
```

is happening on different singleton instances of the  SolrIndexerDriver on different JVMs while

```
SolrIndexerDriver.solrServer.commit
```

is happening on the driver.

In practical terms, the lists on the executors are being filled-in but they are never committed and on the driver the opposite is happening.

The recommended way to handle this is to use `foreachPartition` like this:

```
rdd.foreachPartition{iter =>
  // prepare connection
  Stuff.connect(...)
  // add elements
  iter.foreach(elem => Stuff.add(elem))
  // submit
  Stuff.commit()
}
```

This way you can add the data of each partition and commit the results in the local context of each executor.  Be aware that this add/commit must be thread safe in order to avoid data loss or corruption.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked under the spark UI to see the execution plan of this job.
Check how it is getting split into stages and their dependencies. That should give you an idea hopefully.